# laravel 5.1 how to use Storage->get() in view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I need load my files in storage/app/folder/file.ex in view and I use Storage . but have problem with image source. 
[image]

```
<img src="{{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk('local')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix() . $article->singer_id . '\\' . $article->img}}" >
```

how can i fix this ?

Comment: images are in storage directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I also like to keep my images in the storage folder for a number of reasons:

- I am in control of access, some images may only be available in closed parts of the website.
- It allows me to modify the image (scale, watermark, ...) before I send it to the browser.
- Files that are uploaded by the user (trough a CMS or something) should not be directly publicly accesable, as this may produce a security risk.
- It is much easier to keep them out of my git repository, I just ignore the entire /storage folder.

To make them accesable, you'll need to send your requests trough some sort of ImageController. This needs to be able to do at least 2 things:

- Locate the actual image file based on some sort of slug or filename provided in the path.
- Send the response with all the appropriate headers so the browsers knows it is dealing with an image.

The first part I leave up to you. My code actually uses a database table to store the image information, and does a number of operations with the actual image file to resize and stuff.

The actual sending of the image is slightly complicated since you need to take some cache handling into account, so let me share how I take care of that:

```
protected function sendImage(FilesystemAdapter $storage, $file)
    {
        $data = $storage->get($file);
        $response = response($data)
            ->header('Content-Type', $storage->mimeType($file));

        // Cache for 5 HOURS
        $response->setExpires(Carbon::createFromTimestamp(time() + (60*60*5)));

        //header('Last-Modified: ' . $lastModified);
        $response->setLastModified(Carbon::createFromTimestamp($storage->lastModified($file)));

        //header('ETag: ' . $eTag);
        // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag
        $response->setEtag(md5($data));

        $notModified = false;
        $lastModified = $response->getLastModified();
        $modifiedSince = \Request::header('If-Modified-Since');

        if (!is_null($modifiedSince)) {
            // Check the etag header
            if ($etags = \Request::header('etag')) {
                $notModified = in_array($response->getEtag(), $etags) || in_array('*', $etags);
            }

            // Check if the image is not modified since the latest cache
            if ($modifiedSince && $lastModified) {
                $notModified = strtotime($modifiedSince) >= $lastModified->getTimestamp() && (!$etags || $notModified);
            }

            // If so, send a 'not modified' response
            if ($notModified) {
                $response->setNotModified();
            }
        }

        return $response;
    }
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use image in a view, you should move it to a `public` directory (or one of it's subdirectories) first.

Then you could use it with something like:

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/'.$article->img) }}">
```

Also, make sure you have correct Apache configuration and it's pointed to a `public directory of a Laravel project. For example, if you've uploaded your Laravel projecy to a`c:/wamp/www`, use these settings:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/public"
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/public">
```

Comment: Men my images are in storage folder !

Comment: That's why I told you you must move them to a `public` directory. You can't use them, because web server should be pointed to a `public` directory and web server/browser has access only to files inside that folder.